# Why doesn't Except work when I have defined IEqualityComparer<T>

Tags: c#, linq

If I try to do this - my call to oldList.Except( newList ) seems to return all items - no comparison is working.

```
   List<ControlAndTopLevelControlPair> oldOnly = oldList.Except( newList ).ToList();

   public class ControlAndTopLevelControlPair : IEqualityComparer<ControlAndTopLevelControlPair>
   {
      public int CONTROLOI { get; set; }
      public int VIEWCONTROL_OI { get; set; }
      public bool Equals( ControlAndTopLevelControlPair x, ControlAndTopLevelControlPair y )
      {
         return x.CONTROLOI.Equals( y.CONTROLOI ) && x.VIEWCONTROL_OI.Equals( y.VIEWCONTROL_OI );
      }

      public int GetHashCode( ControlAndTopLevelControlPair obj )
      {
         return obj.CONTROLOI.GetHashCode( ) ^ obj.VIEWCONTROL_OI.GetHashCode( );
      }
```

But if I define a custom comparer then the following works:

```
List<ControlAndTopLevelControlPair> oldOnly = oldList.Except( newList, new ControlAndTopLevelControlPairComparer() ).ToList( );

   public class ControlAndTopLevelControlPairComparer : IEqualityComparer<ControlAndTopLevelControlPair>
   {
      public bool Equals( ControlAndTopLevelControlPair x, ControlAndTopLevelControlPair y )
      {
         return x.CONTROLOI.Equals( y.CONTROLOI ) && x.VIEWCONTROL_OI.Equals( y.VIEWCONTROL_OI );
      }

      public int GetHashCode( ControlAndTopLevelControlPair obj )
      {
         return obj.CONTROLOI.GetHashCode() ^ obj.VIEWCONTROL_OI.GetHashCode();
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IEqualityComparer` is the interface in which you define an object who's sole job is to *compare some other objects*.

You use the `IEquatable` object to define how an object compares *itself* for equality with another object.  If you do that, then you don't need to create a new comparer object and pass it into `Except`.

Ensure that whenever you implement `IEquatble` that you override the object's `GetHashCode` method as well.

```
public class ControlAndTopLevelControlPair : IEquatable<ControlAndTopLevelControlPair>
{
    public int CONTROLOI { get; set; }
    public int VIEWCONTROL_OI { get; set; }
    public bool Equals(ControlAndTopLevelControlPair other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        return CONTROLOI.Equals(other.CONTROLOI)
            && VIEWCONTROL_OI.Equals(other.VIEWCONTROL_OI);
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as ControlAndTopLevelControlPair);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return CONTROLOI.GetHashCode() ^ VIEWCONTROL_OI.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

If you're going to override `GetHashCode` you should also override the object's `Equals` method so that the two definitions of equality stay in sync.

Answer (score 2):

When you don't specify a Comparer, it will default to calls to `GetHashCode` and `Equals(object)`, which you don't implement.

If you put a breakpoint in your methods, you'll see they're never called.  If you do the same with your implementations of `GetHashCode()` and `Equals(object)`, you'll see those *are* called.

```
public class ControlAndTopLevelControlPair 
{
  public int CONTROLOI { get; set; }
  public int VIEWCONTROL_OI { get; set; }

  public override int GetHashCode() {  return CONTROLOI ^ VIEWCONTROL_OI; }
  public override bool Equals (object other) 
  {
     // your implementation
  }
}
```

Comment: Another product of `copying and pasting from the OP's code`? the `IEqualityComparer...` is not needed otherwise you have to add code implementing that interface.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `override` the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in the first case.

```
public class ControlAndTopLevelControlPair {
  public int CONTROLOI { get; set; }
  public int VIEWCONTROL_OI { get; set; }
  public override bool Equals(object x)
  {
     ControlAndTopLevelControlPair c = x as ControlAndTopLevelControlPair;
     if(c == null) return false;
     return c.CONTROLOI.Equals(CONTROLOI) && c.VIEWCONTROL_OI.Equals(VIEWCONTROL_OI);
  }

  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
     return CONTROLOI.GetHashCode( ) ^ VIEWCONTROL_OI.GetHashCode( );
  }
}
```

Note the `override` keywords, the class doesn't need to implement `IEqualityComparer`